# Proving inverse of transpose is transpose of inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm to prove that $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$ but I'm not really getting anywhere.

What I've got so far:

$\frac{1}{detA} \cdot A^T = \left( \frac{1}{detA} \cdot A \right) ^T$

But that gets me nowhere...Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that 
$$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$
we have
$$I_n=(AA^{-1})^T=(A^{-1})^TA^T$$
so 
$$(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$$

Comment: Why does the identity equal the transpose of the identity? Also, I get $(A^{-1})^T = A^T$ by multiplying by $A^T$ on both sides...$IA^T = A^T$...?

Comment: If $A=(a_{ij})$ then $A^T=(a_{ji})$ so what's the transpose of a diagonal matrix?